# Sum of complex radicals squared

Tags: complex-numbers

I am solving an exercise of complex numbers. The problem is that my result was -12 and the correct result is 12i.

Exercise:

[image]

My development:

[image: Exercise resolved]

Could you tell me what I'm failing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you've stumbled upon is the common error called [Freshman's Dream](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Freshman%27s_dream). The core problem is that's not how you square quantities. $(a-b)^2$ is $a^2-2ab+b^2$, not $(a^2-b^2)$.

That said, the answer is not $12i$ because there are both real and imaginary terms once you square the quantity, since you do not have a difference of squares.

Comment: I think you should have stopped after the first teo sentences. Then the OP could have finished.

Comment: @EthanBolker Nevermind, I misunderstood your comment. Removed the last part altogether, just mentioning that there should be both real and imaginary terms.

Comment: Yes, more confirmation is needed. I'd have let the OP do it himself after pointing him in the right direction. But I upvoted because of the first two sentences.

Comment: @EthanBolker Got it. I'm fairly new to Math.SE, which seems to be more hint oriented. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Sometimes hints are appropriate, sometimes complete answers. It's a judgment call, not a rule.

Comment: Which is correct ? raise the $sqrt{-8}$ to -8 or $8i^2$

Comment: @Eduardot I don't understand your comment. Why are you raising to a power other than 2?

Comment: When you make the binomial squared, the first term is a square root of -8.

Should I raise 8i squared or square root of -8 squared? Since 8i squared is -64 and the root of -8 squared is -8

Comment: @Eduardot So you have $(2\sqrt 2 i - 2)^2$ right? Then just fully write it out and distribute. You should get $(2\sqrt 2 i)^2 + 2(2\sqrt 2 i)(-2) + (-2)^2$.

Comment: Many thanks !!!